# Use and implications of eval('expression') in MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, eval

I was encountered with usage of function **eval(expression)** in somebody else's code in matlab: 
for example:

```
for n = 1 : 4
sn = int2str( n) ;
eval( [ 'saveas( fig'  sn  ', [ sName' sn ' ], ''fig'' ) ' ] );
end
```

MathWorks stuff in Matlab Help pointed out that:

> Many common uses of the eval function are less efficient and are more difficult to read and debug than other MATLAB functions and language constructs.

After this, I find usage of this function in many other program languages, so as Python, JavaScript, PHP.

So I have a few questions:

1. Will usage of this function be enfluenced on the performance of my code?
2. If it will slow down execution, why does it occur?
3. If it slow down execution every time when called, what reason for use this function in principle?

Comment: Never ever use eval, dunno if for MATLAB this is untrue but i don't think

Comment: I think you will have a hard to time finding a valid use case for `eval` in Python, JavaScript or PHP. Not sure about MATLAB, though, as I don't know what constructs are available there (and more important: what constructs are *not* available).

Comment: @yes123: Never, ever, make generalizations like these.

Comment: `eval` in Javscript is not that useful. Most of the time you can write it in a better way, ie. wrapping it in anonymous function...

Comment: Just for the record: I remember a recent Python question with an excellent answer using `eval`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9969179/916657

Comment: I am closing this question because it is "not focused enough" and "not constructive" without an analysis of a *particular* language/environment/use. I have yet to find a need/use ... except for some wonderfully clever IE hacks for sidebar gadgets ... or an interactive Python network simulation tool ... (so, twice in about 10 years.)

Comment: @pst: this question is about Matlab, so with the retag, I think it can stay open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Using eval here will certainly be slower than a non-eval version, but most likely it won't be a bottleneck in you code. However, the performance is only one issue, maintenance (incl. debugging), as well as readability are other ones.
2. The slowdown occurs because Matlab uses a JIT compiler, and `eval` lines cannot be optimized.
3. Eval use is in most cases due to lack of knowledge about the Matlab functionality that would be appropriate instead. In this particular case, the issue is that the figure handles are stored in variable names called `fig1` through `fig4`. If they had been stored in an array called `fig`, i.e. `fig(1)` etc, `eval` would have been unnecessary.

**EDIT** Here are two excellent articles by Loren Shure about why `eval` should be avoided in Matlab. [Evading eval](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), and [More on eval](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/01/04/more-in-eval/).

Answer (score 6):

The `eval` function is **dangerous** and there are very few examples where you actually need it. For example, the code you gave can easily be rewritten if you store the figure handles in an array `fig(1)`, `fig(2)` etc and write

```
for n = 1:4
  filename = sprintf('sName%d', n);
  saveas(fig(n), filename, 'fig');
end
```

which is clearer, uses fewer characters, can be analysed by the Matlab editor's linter, is more easily modifiable if (when) you need to extend the code, and is less prone to weird bugs.

As a rule of thumb, you should never use `eval` in any language unless you really know what you are doing (i.e. you are writing a complicated Lisp macro or something else equivalent to manipulating the AST of the language - if you don't know what that means, you probably don't need to use `eval`).

There are almost always clearer, more efficient and less dangerous ways to achieve the same result. Often, a call to `eval` can be replaced with some form of [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science), a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_function) or a loop.

Comment: This won't work. `fig1` is a variable that contains a figure handle. `name` is a variable that contains a string.

Comment: Good point - not familiar enough with the syntax of `saveas`! I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the slowdown occurs because the string has to be parsed into actual code. This isn't such a major issue if used sparingly, but if you ever find yourself using it in code that loops (either an explicit loop or things like JavaScript's `setInterval()`) then you're in for a major performance drop.

Common uses I've seen for `eval` that could be done better are:

- Accessing property names in the ignorance of `[]` notation
- Calling functions based on an argument name, which could instead be done with a `switch` (safer, prevents risk of code injection)
- Accessing variables named like `var1`, `var2`, `var3` when they should be arrays instead

To be honest, I don't think I've ever encountered a single situation where `eval` is the only way to solve a problem. I guess you could liken it to `goto` in that it's a substitute for program structure, or useful as a temporary solution to test a program before spending the time making it work optimally.

Comment: I wouldn't say using it `setInterval` is a "[major] performance drop" ... intervals run, what, 20times/second for a fast one? And how many tens-of-thousands of lines of code can a modern engine "parse" near-instantly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implication:

When you compile a program that uses `eval`, you must put pragmas that tell the compiler that some functions are needed. For example:

This code will compile and run well:

```
 foo()
```

But this one needs a pragma added:

```
 %#function foo
 eval('foo()')
```

Otherwise you will encounter a runtime problem.