# Generalise indexing of a multi-dimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to generalise to any `n` the Matlab code below.

Let `A` be an `n`-dimensional array:

```
clear
rng default
n=4;
A=randn(n,n,n,n); 

n=5;
A=randn(n,n,n,n,n);
```

Note that `A` is composed of `n^(n-2)` 2-dimensional matrices, each of size `nxn`.

For example, when `n=4` these matrices are `A(:,:,1,1),...,A(:,:,4,1),A(:,:,1,2),...,A(:,:,4,4)`.

Suppose I'm interested in a code which:

1) deletes the last column and row in each of the `n^(n-2)`  2-dimensional matrices

```
%when n=4
A(n,:,:,:)=[];
A(:,n,:,:)=[];


%when n=5
A(n,:,:,:,:)=[];
A(:,n,:,:,:)=[];
```

2) deletes the  2-dimensional  matrices with the 3-th,4-th,5-th,n-th index equal to `n`.

```
%when n=4
A(:,:,n,:)=[];
A(:,:,:,n)=[];

%when n=5
A(:,:,n,:,:)=[];
A(:,:,:,n,:)=[];
A(:,:,:,:,n)=[];
```

**Question:** could you help me to generalise the code above to any `n`? I cannot see how to proceed.

Comment: Do you need `A(n,:,:,:)=[];A(:,n,:,:)=[];A(:,:,n,:)=[];A(:,:,:,n)=[];` ? It is the same as `A(1:n-1, 1:n-1, 1:n-1, 1:n-1)`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the number of "commas" inside `A` in your comment depends on `n`. For example, in your comment you are using 3 commas, i.e., you are assuming `n=4`. Instead, I want to be generic.

Comment: If `n=3`: `A(1:n-1,1:n-1, 1:n-1)`. If `n=4`: `A(1:n-1,1:n-1, 1:n-1, 1:n-1)`. If `n=5`: `A(1:n-1,1:n-1, 1:n-1, 1:n-1, 1-n-1)`, etc.

Comment: Use `idx = repmat({1:n-1},1,n); A(idx{:})`. If it is correct let me to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index your matrix with a cell containing multiple elements. Each element will be interpreted as a new index ([more information here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/pass-contents-of-cell-arrays-to-functions.html)):

```
%Example 1: A(:,:,1:3,1:3,1:3}
%elements per dimension 
n = 4;
%number of dimension
d = 5;
%random matrix
repdim = repmat({n},d,1)
A = rand(repdim{:});
%We want A(:,:,1:3,1:3,1:3}, so we create c = {1:3,1:3,1:3}
c = repmat({1:n-1},d-2,1);
%Get the new matrix
A = A(:,:,c{:});


%Example 2: A(1:3,1:3,:,:,:}
%elements per dimension 
n = 4;
%number of dimension
d = 5;
%random matrix
repdim = repmat({n},d,1)
A = rand(repdim{:});
%We want A(1:3,1:3,:,:,:}, so we create c1 = {1:3,1:3} and c2 = {':',':',':'}
c1 = repmat({1:n-1},2,1);
c2 = repmat({':'},d-2,1); %thanks to @LuisMendo for the suggestion.
%Get the new matrix
A = A(c1{:},c2{:});
```

Comment: Would it be beneficial to generalize this further for the `randn` function by creating an input string and then use `eval` to run the command

Comment: @medicine_man: `eval` is never beneficial. Pretend it doesn't exist! You can call `randn` with a single size argument: `randn([n,n,n,n])` -- I bet you know how to generalize that to any number of dimensions. Otherwise you could do: `indx={n,n,n,n}; randn(indx{:})`.

Comment: @obchardon: You can use the string `':'` in your indexing cell array too. That would simplify the code a bit.

Comment: I have never had any issues with `eval`, although many others seem to not like this command. I have no idea why, honestly.

Comment: @medicine_man: it's a security risk, it slows down code, it makes code harder to read, etc. etc. There are many Q&As here that discuss the issues with `eval`. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272522/use-and-implications-of-evalexpression-in-matlab-code/10272578

Comment: Actually, you are not indexing a matrix with a cell array (that's not possible). Rather, you are indexing a matrix with the _comma-separated list_ generated from a cell array. Also, the suggestion you refer to was not mine :-)