# Generalise calling of Matlab function with generic number of inputs

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a pre-built Matlab function

```
function A=f(varagin)
...
end
```

I call `f.m` in a file `main.m`.

When calling `f.m`, the inputs to include depend on the number of columns of two matrices `X` and `Y`.

For example, if

```
d=2;
X=randn(4,d);
Y=randn(4,d);
```

then

```
A=f(X(:,1),X(:,2),Y(:,1),Y(:,2));
```

If

```
d=3;
X=randn(4,d);
Y=randn(4,d);
```

then

```
A=f(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3),Y(:,1),Y(:,2),Y(:,3));
```

If

```
d=4;
X=randn(4,d);
Y=randn(4,d);
```

then

```
A=f(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3),X(:,4),Y(:,1),Y(:,2),Y(:,3),Y(:,4));
```

Could you help me to generalise the calling of `f.m` in `main.m` with any `d`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is more or less identical to that of [your previous question about indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57463992/7328782):

```matlab
args = {arg1, arg2, arg3};
f(args{:});
```

`args{:}` generates a comma-separated list of its elements, which is thus equivalent to using each of its elements as an argument to the function.

To convert the columns of a numeric matrix to a cell array, use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).