# Unable to understand the looping logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a problem using Python.
The problem: Given a string like 'a b c d', replace the space with '_' for all combinations.
So here, the expected output would be:
'a_b c d',
'a_b_c d',
'a_b_c_d',
'a b_c d',
'a b_c_d',
'a b c_d'

I am using a sliding window approach for this, here's my code:

```
ip = 'a b c d'
org = ip
res = []

for i in range(len(ip)):
    if ip[i] == ' ': i += 1
    for j in range(i + 1, len(ip)):
        if ip[j] == ' ':
            ip = ip[:j] + '_' + ip[j+1:]
            res.append(ip)
        j += 1
    i += 1
    ip = org
```

The problem is, the 2nd for loop is looping twice and appending duplicate results.

Result: `['a_b c d', 'a_b_c d', 'a_b_c_d', 'a b_c d', 'a b_c_d', 'a b_c d', 'a b_c_d', 'a b c_d', 'a b c_d']`

I am not able to figure why this is happening, would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: `ip = org` is not creating a copy. You may find it helpful to read through [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: You are modifying `ip` in the 2nd loop while looping over it in both loops. This can lead to unexpected behaviour. Ideally use a different variable name here to avoid confusion.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, isn't `a b c d`, `a_b c d`, `a b_c d`, `a_b_c d`, `a b c_d`, `a_b c_d`, `a b_c_d`, `a_b_c_d` the full list of combinations?

Comment: @AKX there are duplicates

Comment: Also, this `if ip[i] == ' ': i += 1` doesn't advance your `for` loop. What you want is something like `if ip[i] == ' ': continue`.

Comment: How is your expected output just 6 elements?

Comment: @Axe319, thanks so much! `if ip[i] == ' ': i += 1` was the culprit.

Comment: @mozway What duplicates? Your solution gives the same list as what I posted there.

Comment: @AKX I meant in the output from OP's code

Answer (score 1):

Beyond `itertools.product`, there's a neat binary trick you can do here since you're essentially flipping "bits" at given indices in the string:

```
ip = 'a b c d'

# Figure out where the spaces are.
space_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(ip) if x == ' ']
# Loop over all numbers from 0 (no bits set) to 2^N-1 (all bits set)
for x in range(1 << len(space_indices)):
    new_ip = list(ip)
    for i, pos in enumerate(space_indices):  # loop over every "bit"
        if x & (1 << i):  # if the i-th bit is set...
            new_ip[pos] = '_'  # ... replace with an underscore
    print("".join(new_ip))
```

This prints out

```
a b c d
a_b c d
a b_c d
a_b_c d
a b c_d
a_b c_d
a b_c_d
a_b_c_d
```

For a reverse order, you can switch to `if not`.

The loop body could also be

```
    # Figure out which positions to replace with underscores
    # by looking at which bits are set in `x`.
    to_replace = {pos for i, pos in enumerate(space_indices) if x & (1 << i)}
    # Print out a string with some of the characters replaced.
    print("".join("_" if pos in to_replace else c for pos, c in enumerate(ip)))
```

if you like a more functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here:

```
from itertools import product, chain

ip = 'a b c d'
words = ip.split()

res = [''.join(chain(*zip(words, p), words[-1]))
       for p in product([' ', '_'], repeat=len(words)-1)]
```

Output:

```
['a b c d',
 'a b c_d',
 'a b_c d',
 'a b_c_d',
 'a_b c d',
 'a_b c_d',
 'a_b_c d',
 'a_b_c_d']
```

Comment: the order differs from the expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there are several ways to change the order if this is important ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903257/python-itertools-product-reorder-the-generation)). I'll try to update with a simple approach

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help everyone, especially @Axe319. The issue was with the second line in the for loop, here's the fixed solution:

```
ip = 'a b c d'
org = ip
res = []

for i in range(len(ip)):
    if ip[i] == ' ': continue
    for j in range(i + 1, len(ip)):
        if ip[j] == ' ':
            ip = ip[:j] + '_' + ip[j+1:]
            res.append(ip)
        j += 1
    i += 1
    ip = org
```

Comment: Well, you do not have `'a_b c_d'` in your output

Answer (score 0):

With `str.find` and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) functions (with specifying the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced):

```
import re

ip = 'a b c d'
sep_cnt = ip.count(' ')  # count number of spaces
res = []
sep_pos = ip.find(' ')  # get separator position
for i in range(sep_cnt):
    for j in range(sep_cnt - i):  # countdown replacements
        res.append(ip[:sep_pos] + re.sub(r' ', '_', ip[sep_pos:], j + 1))
    sep_pos = ip.find(' ', sep_pos + 1)

print(res)
```

---

```
['a_b c d', 'a_b_c d', 'a_b_c_d', 'a b_c d', 'a b_c_d', 'a b c_d']
```